# Dirac Delta potential and perturbation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, scattering

I have a Dirac Delta potential as follows :
$$V(x)= - \alpha \delta (x)$$

I know how to solve that problem. There is exactly one bound state.

Now let's say I have an initial wave function in this potential given by $$ d(x)=- \sqrt{\beta} e^{- \beta |x|}$$ I know that if $\alpha = \beta$, then the initial state is the bound state which is stationary and will not change in time.  Now if beta is different than alpha, then the initial state will be the right shape of the bound state but scaled up or down. I am wondering if I can think of this in the following way:
The initial state can be decomposed into a sum of the bound state plus an integral over scattering states.
If I wait long enough, the scattering states are either reflected or transmitted and they will eventually scatter to infinity.
Thus taking the limit of time to infinity means I recover the actual bound state of the potential.
Is this a correct view?